# É possível replicar uma union no Java?

Tags: java, union

As `union`s que eu me refiro são as mesmas do C/C++. O objetivo da `union` é economizar memória utilizando a mesma região dela para armazenar dados diferentes em momentos diferentes.

É como um quarto de hotel. Diferentes pessoas vivem nele por períodos de tempo que não se sobrepõem. Essas pessoas nunca se encontram e geralmente não sabem nada uma da outra. Ao gerenciar adequadamente o tempo compartilhado dos quartos (ou seja, garantir que pessoas diferentes não sejam designadas para um quarto ao mesmo tempo), um hotel razoavelmente pequeno pode oferecer acomodações para um número relativamente grande de pessoas.

É possível replicar este comportamento no Java? Se sim, como?

Eu não tenho a menor ideia de como seria possível fazer algo parecido no Java, nem sei se ao menos ele permite gerenciamento de memória, então agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Talvez ajude, mas não tenho certeza quanto a eficácia: https://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-union-ou-semelhante-em-java/81499/13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comportamento geral é possível através de biblioteca que tenha uma estrutura que simule isto, mas replicar o comportamento específico de uma `union` do C não dá, a linguagem não possui mecanismo para isto (ao contrário do C#).

`union` é muito eficiente e é usado principalmente para comunicar com o hardware. Java não faz essa comunicação diretamente e o todo é tão ineficiente em outras coisas que seria até ridículo ter um mecanismo que faça esse tipo de economia ao extremo (C# já gosta de comunicar com coisas de baixo nível e ter menos camadas interferindo, mesmo assim tem limitações).

Uma biblioteca dá essa capacidade mas você terá um objeto enorme, alocando no *heap*, em muitos casos nem compensa o uso. Isso poderá mudar com o novo tipo por valor que Java terá nas próximas versões, mas ainda não terá o mesmo nível de eficiência. [Exemplo](http://javolution.org/apidocs/javolution/io/Union.html).

Até existe alguma forma de fazer com código inseguro, mas é bem complexo, e na verdade qualquer coisa é possível fazer com código inseguro, foge do escopo do Java em si. E não quer dizer que tenha a mesma eficiência, apenas que se aproxima em alguns pontos.

Comment: Se eu utilizar métodos nativos, ficaria muito complexo a comunicação entre a `union` do C/C++ e o resto do código em Java? Ou seria viável?

Comment: Viável é, mas não compensa na imensa maioria dos casos, Java optou por tornar muito difícil fazer isto. Quando eles criaram tinham uma visão de linguagem pura.